# "On the whole" usage

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I want to say something like this,

> **"Blaming people on the whole *(all the people)* is what he always does"**

I mean the person is always ***judging/blaming all the people (or some specific group of people)*** for someone else's mistake.

I have seen some examples with *"One the whole"* like the below one,

`On the whole, it was a good party`. 
But it means `Overall, it was a good party`

*"overall=generally speaking"* which is not the meaning I'm looking for.

I'm looking for a word to mean `all the people / whole people`

So I want to know, Can I use **"on the whole"** here in the example to mean **"all the people"**?

> **"Judging *people on the whole* for someone else's mistake is not a good thing"**

I have tried my best to explain this question. Sorry If I haven't made the question clear enough.

Please help me.

Comment: This dictionary website has the word "upon the whole". http://www.dictionary.com/browse/as--a--whole

Answer (score -1):

Well, "to blame on" is a phrasal verb, so i think that one must be the right one, and "the hole" it's just the adjective of a noun, as in this example:

•He BLAMED the dog ON THE WHOLE mess

Comment: ***He blamed the whole mess  on the dog***. And blame on is not a phrasal verb at all.

Comment: Yes it is, you can look it up

Comment: This is the problem with google and company, it can be very misleading And ***He blamed the dog on the whole mess*** is very, very unidiomatic. ***To blame something [direct object] on [someone or something]***.  This is just a fact, really.